# How to execute code in Django if an error occurs?

Tags: django, django-views

One of the views that I call works with two database tables. It attempts to find an object in the first table. If the object isn't found, I get a Server Error (500). I'm not sure what the code would look like, but I want to insert some code into the view that will execute if the Server Error occurs so that I can tell it to try to find the object in the second table.

Current Code:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def addEvent(request):
    event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    user = request.POST['profile']
    event = Event.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    if event.DoesNotExist:
        event = customEvent.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    user = Profile.objects.get(id = user)
    user.eventList.add(event)

    return HttpResponse(status = 200)
```

Comment: What is your exact code?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: By the way, you should probably figure out a method to enable csrf on this view as having it exempt can cause security issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are getting 500 error because you are not finding a record in the first table. To fix that, you just have to catch the `DoesNotExist` Exception (Mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#get)):

```
try:
    obj = FooModel.objects.get(...)
except FooModel.DoesNotExist:
    try:
        obj = OtherModel.objects.get(...)
    except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

or you can simplify this by using a [shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
try:
    obj = FooModel.objects.get(...)
except FooModel.DoesNotExist:
    obj = get_object_or_404(OtherModel, ...)
```

Comment: I thought that too. Here is the error I'm getting though.

TypeError: 'Event' instance expected, got <customEvent: Chrome>

Comment: You can't use an if statement, because as you have seen an if statement will not catch the error. You must use the try/except code, because it is designed to catch errors

Comment: Ahhh I found what was wrong. The ManyToMany only exists between one of the objects. So when it tries to link to the 2nd one, it gets the type error.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to fix this?

I have
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='event_set+')

I need eventList to connect to customEvent as well